# Access Char Vector in list of Char Vectors

Tags: c++

I am reading a dictionary line by line into a list which consists of vectors of char each representing one word.
The dictionary looks like this:

```
aaaaa
aaaab   
aaaac
```

And each word is separated  by a new line delim in the dictionary. It contains about 140k words. My Code must be compatible with c. Thats why I am trying to use a char array. My problem is that if I compile my Code it prints the word but an exeption is thrown "Vector Subscript out of range". I would like to process the list later on and I hope you can help me understand why std::vector acts this way.

My Code looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


std::list<std::vector<char>>dictionary;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("/Users/User/Desktop/Speller/Dictionaries/large", std::ios::in);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(infile, line))
        {
            std::vector<char> data(line.begin(), line.end());
            dictionary.push_back(data);
        }

        auto l_front = dictionary.begin();
        std::advance(l_front, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i != '\n'; i++)
        {
            std::cout << l_front->at(i);
        }


        infile.close();
        return true;
    }
    else if (!(infile.is_open()))
    {
        std::cout << "File not open\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could anbody tell me how I can fix my Code and what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Unless you have very good reasons or requirements, the default container should be `std::vector`. Even if you need to store other vectors.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != '\n'; i++)` I think you meant `l_front->at(i) != '\n'` but `std::getline` discards the newline.

Comment: What made you think the condition `i != '\n'` would be fine in the first place? The variable `i` is an *index* not a character.

Comment: On another note, if you have `if (condition) { ... } else if (!condition) { ... }` that's really the same as `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`. You don't need to negate the same condition.

Comment: And what happens if there's not five elements in `dictionary`? Always check that *first* before advancing.

Comment: And regarding the loop again, what you *might* want is simply `for (auto c : *l_front) { std::cout << c; }`

Comment: Thank you guys for the awesome input. Some programmer dude's code works perfectly. I did not know a pointer can actually point to a whole array :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My Code looks like this now - Ty All

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>


std::pair<bool, std::list<std::vector<char>> > load();

int main()
{ 
    // Load dictionary
    auto [loaded, dictionary] = load();

    //if (dictionary.size() <= 1)
    if (loaded == false)
        return 1;
    
      auto l_front = dictionary.begin();
    

    if (dictionary.size() <= 5)
    {
        std::advance(l_front, 5);

        for (char c : *l_front)
        {
            std::cout << c;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}



std::pair<bool, std::list<std::vector<char>> > load()
{
    std::list<std::vector<char>> dictionary;

    std::ifstream infile("/Users/User/Desktop/Speller/Dictionaries/large", std::ios::in);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(infile, line))
        {
            std::vector<char> data(line.begin(), line.end());
            dictionary.push_back(data);
        }
        infile.close();
        return std::make_pair(true, dictionary);
    }
    std::cout << "Cant find file\n";
    return std::make_pair(false, dictionary);

}
```